# Virtual measurement device with line series chart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChart JS and would like to implement a virtual measurement device, where I can click on point A and then drag to point B and obtain the x,y values of both point A and point B.

As far as I have looked into the event handlers they just return a mouse event with start and stop positions in terms of screen positions. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. Also please suggest an efficient way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse events return the mouse coordinates in the same coordinate space as normal JS mouse events. To get the click location in the series coordinate space, a couple of steps need to be taken.

First the mouse coordinates need to be converted to the engine coordinate space. The engine coordinate space is the canvas area with 0,0 on the bottom left of the canvas. This can be done with [`chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(ev.clientX,ev.clientY)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/interfaces/publicengine.html#clientlocation2engine). This returns the event coordinate in the engine coordinate space using the chart engine scale.

This needs to be then converted to the series coordinate. This can be done with [`translatePoint`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/globals.html#translatepoint) method. `translatePoint` can be used to convert points between two different scales. Scale in LightningChart JS is basically a coordinate space.

```js
const m = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(ev.clientX, ev.clientY)
const translated = translatePoint(m, chart.engine.scale, lineSeries.scale)
```

Now the `translated` variable contains the click location in the series coordinate space.

See a full code snippet below where you can drag on the series area and when drag is stopped markers are placed to the start and end locations of the drag.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidLine,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    UIOrigins,
    DataPatterns,
    translatePoint,
    ColorHEX
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const diesel = [
    { x: 0, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 1, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 2, y: 1.52 },
    { x: 3, y: 1.58 },
    { x: 4, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 5, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 6, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 7, y: 2.00 },
    { x: 8, y: 2.26 },
    { x: 9, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 10, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 11, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 12, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 13, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 14, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 15, y: 1.60 },
    { x: 16, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 17, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 18, y: 1.00 },
    { x: 19, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 20, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 21, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 22, y: 1.47 },
    { x: 23, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 24, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 25, y: 1.74 },
    { x: 27, y: 1.5 },
    { x: 28, y: 1.5 },
    { x: 29, y: 1.5 }
]

const gasoline = [
    { x: 0, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 1, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 2, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 3, y: 1.35 },
    { x: 4, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 5, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 6, y: 1.90 },
    { x: 7, y: 1.92 },
    { x: 8, y: 1.50 },
    { x: 9, y: 1.50 },
    { x: 10, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 11, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 12, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 13, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 14, y: 1.3 },
    { x: 15, y: 1.32 },
    { x: 16, y: 1.40 },
    { x: 17, y: 1.44 },
    { x: 18, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 19, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 20, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 21, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 22, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 23, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 24, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 25, y: 1.02 },
    { x: 27, y: 1.30 },
    { x: 28, y: 1.30 },
    { x: 29, y: 1.30 }
]

const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive })

const lineSeries2 = chart.addLineSeries({ dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive })

lineSeries2.add(diesel.map((point) => ({ x: point.x, y: point.y })))
lineSeries.add(gasoline.map((point) => ({ x: point.x, y: point.y })))


const markerA = chart.addChartMarkerXY()
    .setPointMarker((marker) => marker.setFillStyle((f => f.setColor(ColorHEX('#f00')))))
    .setMouseInteractions(false)
const markerB = chart.addChartMarkerXY()
    .setPointMarker((marker) => marker.setFillStyle((f => f.setColor(ColorHEX('#0f0')))))
    .setMouseInteractions(false)

function getClickInSeriesScale(point, scale) {
    const m = chart.engine.clientLocation2Engine(point.x, point.y)
    return translatePoint(m, chart.engine.scale, scale)
}

chart.onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStop((obj, ev, b, start) => {
    let pointA = getClickInSeriesScale(start, lineSeries.scale)
    let pointB = getClickInSeriesScale({x:ev.clientX,y:ev.clientY}, lineSeries.scale)

    // move markes to start and end points
    markerA.setPosition(pointA)
    markerB.setPosition(pointB)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer is there any way where we can have the zoom functionality along with this?

Comment: Zooming works fine with it. I had just forgotten to remove code that disables zooming. :) I have now re-enabled zooming in the example code.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for bugging you but this returns only the starting position right?
I would like to extract the ending position of the drag too.

Comment: I have updated the example snippet again. Now it uses dragging and places one marker at the start position and another to the end position.